# How to run child processes concurrently

Tags: linux, process

I want child processes run concurrently. Is it OK to write as to achieve this:

```
 for(p = 0; p < N; p++){ //there will be N child processes
    pidOfChild = fork();
    if(pidOfChild == -1){
      printf("fork() failed.\n");
      exit(1);
    }
    else if(pidOfChild == 0){
      //do sth
      printf("I am a child and my PID is %d.\n", getpid());
      exit(0);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Yes, it is OK to write it as such.

Comment: Your question is very dubious. Try asking more specifically (didn't downvote, but I guess that's the reason why you got the downvote)

Comment: Is there any specific problem with this code you experience or foresee? (I don't see any).

Comment: I have little experience with processes, that's why I want to be sure.

Comment: It is ok, but you'll need to *later* call [waitpid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html) (or some other waiting syscall) to avoid [Zombie processes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombie_process). See http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is okay, and if your parent process exits, you don't need to `wait`.